# client connects to old server thread and retrieves outdated data?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a client thread that will ping server for one of its status attributes:

```
    def run ( self ):

    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(('localhost',2727))

    print 'client #', self.name , 'polling'

    x = client.recv(1024)
    client.close()

    print x
```

my server runs a loop which gets it's state, and spawns a thread for the socket:

```
    while True:

        deviceState = self.getDeviceState()
        channel, details = self.server.accept()
        sThread.ServerThread(channel, details, deviceState).start()
```

The issue is that after I update the deviceState and the client pings, it first gets the old state (probably from an existing ServerThread) no matter how long I wait. Then when the client pings again, it can pick up the new state. Is there a way to shutdown the ServerThread if deviceState is updated and make sure the client socket gets a fresh server thread?

Comment: Sorry for the indentation on run(), that whole code block is in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sThread.ServerThread()` is your function, right?

Instead of getting the device state and passing it as an argument to `ServerThread()`, have your implementation of `ServerThread()` do a call to `.getDeviceState()` after the request comes in to get the latest device state.

The way you have it set up now returns the device state as it was *when the thread was created*, not the device state as it is when the request comes in.

Comment: Noticed this shortly after posting the question, but you get a checkmark anyway :P